# How to disable validation on dijit.form.FilteringSelect?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

My [FilteringSelect](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html) have to set `required: true` but can accept any text.

The problem is when the text not match in [store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Memory.html),  the error will appear.

How can I avoid that error?

*Note : This code is working well but its disable `required`'s validator too.*

```
this.myFilteringSelect.validate = function () {
    //NoAction
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `dijit/form/ComboBox` to get the desired behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/ESwpr/